# How do I call outside function from class in python

Tags: python-3.x

How do i call an outside function from this class ?

```
def test(t):
   return t

class class_test():
   def test_def(q):
       test_msg = test('Hi')
       print (test_msg)
```

Comment: What happens when you run code above?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To call the class method, you can create an instance of the class and then call an attribute of that instance (the `test_def` method).

```
def test(t):
    return t

class ClassTest(object):
    def test_def(self):
        msg = test('Hi')
        print(msg)

# Creates new instance.
my_new_instance = ClassTest()
# Calls its attribute.
my_new_instance.test_def()
```

Alternatively you can call it this way:

```
ClassTest().test_def()
```

---

<sub>Sidenote: I made a few changes to your code. `self` should be used as first argument of class methods when you define them. `object` should be used in a similar manner.</sub>

Comment: Want access the test(t) function inside of the ClassTest,

Comment: @GThamizh What do you mean? Aren't you already using `test(t)` in `test_def()`?

Comment: @sqrcompass what code exactly are you using, what do you expect to get and what do you get?

Comment: @sqrcompass are you by any chance trying to access `test` in another module where you have imported `ClassTest` (in the example above)? That is, trying something like `ClassTest.test`.